# Scaffold drawer conditional rendering throwing an error

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer, scaffold

I need to display a Scaffold drawer only for the portrait mode of some specific devices. I'm using conditional rendering (the showDrawer is true when the specific devices are met)

```
Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    drawer: showDrawer ? drawer : null,
    body: Text('test')
)
```

This is not breaking the app (it works) but it is giving me a console error when I rotate the devices

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked. 

This Scaffold widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is locked.
```

I tried changing the conditional to:

```
drawer: showDrawer ? drawer : const SizedBox(),
```

but then the drawer overlay displays and hides the UI. Removing the conditional makes the console error disappear.

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I found an open issue on the Flutter's github repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34978 - Looks like it could be related